# How do I start a new conversation in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I just tried starting a new conversation in chat, I was told there was an error, and there was a link for me to come here at give any additional information I could.  First, I am new to chat here so if there is some information I am missing just let me know.  I did read the FAQs, and ultimately that is how this started.

I was looking for information on how to start a new discussion as I could not find the link.  The FAQ did not answer that question, but at the bottom of the FAQ it provided a link to the sandbox so I could ask more questions.  Someone provided me with a link to start a new conversation, but then it errored out.  They also informed me that the link is normally at the bottom of the main conversation page.  Yet I do not see it.

Is there a minimum rep score to start a new conversation?

Comment: Which chat room do you want to participate in?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Sorry I need to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @ProtoNoob You should try to ask just one question at a time here. Post the question about your 1 rep here as a new question please

Comment: I searched to see if any conversations had anything near the topic I was looking for and found none.  So, I was trying to start my own conversation.  I want to expand a discussion happening in a Q&A into a more informal back and forth so we are not muddying that page with trouble shooting.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908853/separating-designers-from-main-assembly

Comment: @CanadianLuke - I will remove the second question, but I'm only tangentially interested in that as I figured that might have been the cause of the main issue.  I will not be asking that question elsewhere.

Comment: @ProtoNoob For your 2nd (now renoved question).  Meta.StackOverflow is special for historical reasons, specifically it also serves as Meta.StackExchange as well.  It has its own rep system, unlike the per-site metas that share rep with the parent site.

Comment: I started a freture-requst to add an [Option to continue a discussion in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233548)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a conversation you need 100 rep points.  This is not mentioned in the FAQs and I really think it should be.

Comment: You need 15 rep to participate in chat, which you don't have, which is why you couldn't follow a link given to you to.  The room will have been created automatically, so you wouldn't have needed to create it at all.

Comment: @Servy  Actually, at the time that I asked the question I had 95 rep (stackOverflow and stackoverflow chat).  That was in the original question but someone thought it was off topic.

Answer (score 0):

[As explained in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), you need 100 reputation points to create chat rooms and and [1000 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) to create gallery chat rooms.