# Option to continue a discussion in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I would like to invite someone in a comments discussion underneath an answer to continue in Chat, but it doesn't seem to be a problem of that it is ["Let us continue this discussion in chat" no more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229385/let-us-continue-this-discussion-in-chat-no-more)
It seems more that until now there is no possibility to create the room and invite someone before having exchanged at least 9 comments in turns (as tested below)

**Please add an option to create a chatroom and link to it in a comments flow right away.**

Comment: I deleted the *14 comments* it needed to start [this chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/735/discussion-between-rene-and-rubo77)

Comment: In our test in an answer at the "Formatting Sandbox" Topic it worked after 9 comments too. So this request will be just for an option to **start the chat earlyer**

Comment: The amount of comments required changes based on whether you ask it on meta, or the main site.  Main sites have drastically less comments required between two people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Workaround:

[This Chat Howto from the Privileges Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) states:

> ### How do I create a new chat room?
>
> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper left corner of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page.
>   What happens when I create a new room?
>
> After you create the room, you'll want to invite other users into your room -- either using the invite room menu option, or by pasting the URL to your room as a chat message in other rooms you're participating in.

But that is not an easy way to continue a discussion in Chat.